# Why is 'mfrow=c(1, 5)' not giving me 5 plots next to each other?

Tags: r

```
library(lattice)
par(mfrow=c(1, 5))
xyplot(airquality$Ozone ~ airquality$Wind | factor(airquality$Month))
```

[image]

R version 3.0.2

How can I have all 5 plots next to each other? What's wrong with my `mfrow` setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because lattice plots do not use `par("mfrow")` to set the layout of the panels. Use

```
xyplot(airquality$Ozone ~ airquality$Wind | factor(airquality$Month), layout=c(5,1))
```

instead.